# local snapshot not restoring in APFS file system

Tags: macos, high-sierra, apfs

Using `tmutil localsnapshot` I was able to create snapshot(in this format: com.apple.TimeMachine.2017-12-28-032610), but was not able to revert to this snapshot using `tmutil restore` since APFS doesn't show me the path to this snapshot.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Restoring from a snapshot happens when you run the migration assistant or boot to recovery HD / internet recovery.

Follow the restore steps from:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250

The `tmutil restore` command is targeted at one or several individual file copies from my interpretation of the manual page and using it in practice. It works well for "go get this file" or "go get this folder" from that specific backup and not to much for rolling back a checkpoint of the whole system or a large volume of files.